# King on reduced chessboard $2\times 2$ moving randomly, what is the probability that it ends up in one of the corners after $1000$ moves?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

As mentioned in the title, we have a chessboard $2\times2$, the king moves with equal probability to each square on the chessboard. King begins from the left upper corner. What is the approximate probability that the king will be standing in the bottom right corner after a thousand moves? I know how to solve it when the number of steps goes to infinity, which would make the probability $1/4$. But is there any trick to do it for a $1000$ moves or is it just "relatively" large number so that I would use my method to solve it as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: I don't see why $1000$ should be special in any way.

Comment: Since the king is standing on one of the four fields, there are only three options for him to go. So I would say probability is 1/3. Why you think it is 1/4?

Comment: Just getting to know them, I solved the first part using it.

Comment: @James That's if he only makes one move. We are making 1000 random moves one after the other. It's quite easy to make a sequence ending up in any of the four squares.

Comment: It cannot be exactly $\frac{1}{4}$ after any finite number of moves since at any point, the number of possible moves is $3$ and so there are $3^n$ possible sequences of $n$ moves.  If $m$ of these end in the desired location then the probability will be $\frac{m}{3^n}$ which cannot be $\frac{1}{4}$ though it could be very close.

Comment: @badjohn "What is the **approximate** probability that the king will be standing in the bottom right corner after a thousand moves?" It's going to be _pretty darn close_ to $\frac14$, and I believe that that's enough.

Comment: @Arthur I considered calculating it but jmerry beat me to it.  If we trust his result, then it will differ from $\frac{1}{4}$ by about $\frac{1}{5 \times 10^{477}}$ which can be called very close.

Comment: @Arthur This group is maths not engineering.  in engineering, it would be called exactly $\frac{1}{4}$.  If we took that attitude in maths then there would be no irrational numbers.

Comment: @badjohn I'm a bit unclear. Do you agree or disagree that $\frac14$ is a correct answer to the problem as it is stated?

Comment: @Arthur I missed the word "approximate".  So, considering that, $\frac{1}{4}$ is good enough.  It is just that we don't normally deal with approximations here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After $n$ moves, the probabilities of the three squares other than the starting square are equal by symmetry. Let $p_n$ be the probability of being in the lower right square after $n$ moves. Then the probability of being in the upper left after $n$ moves is $1-3p_n$.

We can find a simple recursion here. To reach the lower right square on the $(n+1)$th move, we must be in one of the other three squares (probability $1-p_n$) after the $n$th move, and then make the correct move from there (probability $\frac13$). Thus $p_{n+1}=\frac13(1-p_n)$.

If $e_n=p_n-\frac14$, we then get $e_{n+1}+\frac14=\frac13(\frac34-e_n)=\frac14-\frac13e_n$, so $e_{n+1}=-\frac13 e_n$. Since $p_0=0$ and $e_0=-\frac14$, we get $e_{1000}=-\frac14\cdot \left(-\frac13\right)^{1000}=\frac{-1}{4\cdot 3^{1000}}$ and $p_{1000}=\frac14-\frac{1}{4\cdot 3^{1000}}=\frac{3^{1000}-1}{3^{1000}\cdot 4}$.

There it is. Exact, even.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a Markov chain approach, since OP tagged it:

There are two states: 1) Not being in the bottom right corner, and 2) being in brc. The transition matrix is $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2/3&1\\1/3&0\end{pmatrix}$$ What is being asked is the value of $$p=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot A^{1000}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&(-\frac{1}{3})^{1000}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{1000}}\right)$$ The column $(1,0)$ refers to the starting state of 1) and the left-most $(0,1)$ refers to the end-state 2), with a thousand transitions in between.